# Need to reshape data and I'm confused on pivot vs. stack vs. transpose

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape, transpose

I have data that comes in the following format (see table 1) and need to reshape and stack the data in the way presented in Table 2 (i am not sure if those are the right terms). **Also sorry for the image, I wasn't able to bring in the df with the colors to explain it**.

[image: Table 1 - Input]

I need to convert it to data table 2 - what is the process and what would the proper approach be, pivoting?

[image: Table 2 - DESIRED OUTCOME]

THANKS!!

Comment: I would use `df.stack` or `df.melt`. Doubt it can be done with `pivot` and `transpose`.

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is `df.melt()`

```py
(df.melt(
    id_vars=['Location'], 
    value_vars=[1, 2, 3], 
    var_name='Time', 
    value_name='Value')
   .dropna())
```

It will give you the expected result :

```py
Location Time Value
0   A   1   0.5
1   B   1   0.2
2   A   2   3.0
3   B   2   0.4
4   A   3   2.0
```

You can sort your Location column afterwards if necessary